# Playing ogg files in Visual Studio debugging mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cassini

This might be more of a cassini issue with MIME Types (can you change them? It doesn't look like you can or am I wrong?).

I'm building a site that is using the audio tag to play audio files. For Firefox I'm using ogg.

When I go the to file directly, http://localhost:1455/audio.ogg, instead of playing the file just downloads. What would I need to do to get this working (without resorting to running the site through IIS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) instead of cassini, it is a lightweight version of IIS designed for development and is a drop-in replacement for cassini.

You will get better control over all aspects of the web server.

Comment: Ah ok, looks like that will do the trick. Might wait on SP1's full release before giving it a try (as it'll integrate with VS 2010).